# How to initialize default values in jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, slider

I am using [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/index.html) to make a simple slider that will display dates.
I read the explanaition [here](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#optionsUsage) (*only the first section, no need to read the whole page...*) and now want to make a simple "Hello world" with default values:

- slider range Jan-2014...Jun-2014
- marks are by default placed on April-1 and April-25 (april is month =3).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>         
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <div id="slider"></div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>            
        <script src="jQDateRangeSlider-min.js"></script>



        <script>

            //create the slider
            $("#slider").dateRangeSlider();

            //set options - the the bounds of the slider
            $("#slider").dateRangeSlider(
                      "option",
                      "bounds",
                      {
                        min: new Date(2014, 1, 1),
                        max: new Date(2014, 5, 25)  
                    });

            //set options - the the boundsdefault values of the slider                                                              
            $("#slider").dateRangeSlider(
                      "option",
                      "defaultValues",
                      {
                        min: new Date(2014, 3, 1),
                        max: new Date(2014, 3, 25)  
                    });




        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do see the slier and it is working, but not initializing with the correct values.

It seems pretty straightforward, but the slider does not initialize correctly. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I understand if it's just for your example, but you seem to be initializing the dateRangeSlider 3 separate times on the same element.

Comment: I the documentation it is written that I set options like that, so I set it several times.... Isnt it ok? What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: I wrote this and it initialized the months range: $("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
       bounds: {  min: new Date(2014, 1, 1) , max: new Date(2014, 5, 25) }
    });

Comment: Oh sorry. Realized that something I said didn't apply to the plugin you were using. My answer below was what I was kindof thinking instead of setting options after initialization. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you. I'm just initializing options right away.

```
 $("#slider").dateRangeSlider(
            bounds:
                   {
                      min: new Date(2014, 1, 1),
                      max: new Date(2014, 5, 25)  
                   },
            defaultValues:
                   {
                      min: new Date(2014, 3, 1),
                      max: new Date(2014, 3, 25)
                   } 
    );
```